# Get all available custom options for product

Tags: magento2

I have a `before-`plugin for the `addItem` function of `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`.

In this function I need to access ALL possible options that can be set for my product.

With `$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())['options']`, I can successfully get the options that have been set by the visitor, but not all options.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$item->getProduct()->getOptions()
```